# is it possible to change the color of start button in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

is it possible to change the color of start button in windows 7. or customize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Check out [this link](http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/index.php?/topic/24776-changing-the-windows-7-start-button/).

Summary:

Using [Restorator](http://www.bome.com/products/restorator):

> Restorator -> File -> open " Ctrl+0" ->find explorer.exe
>   explorer.exe -> Bitmap -> replace PNG 6801 , 6805 , 6809 > Assingn..-> Assign To > save
>   Use TakeOwnerShip to replace explorer.exe